# Batch insertion neo4j - best option?

Tags: python, neo4j, batch-processing, batch-insert

I've been trying to import a relatively large dataset into neo4j...approximately 50 million nodes with relationships.

I first experimented with Cypher via py2neo -> which does work, but becomes very slow if you need to use CREATE UNIQUE or MERGE.

I'm now looking at other batch import methods, and I'm wondering if there are recommendations for which of these approaches is the best for general workflow and speed:

- The Neo4j docs mention a [batch insertion facility](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html) that appears to be Java and is part of the Neo4j distribution;
- There is also the [batch inserter](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/tree/20) by Michael Hunger over at github, I am not sure how similar or different this is from the one included in the distribution;
- Then there is also the [load2neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo), which I'm currently testing;
- And then there is the [load from CSV](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html?_ga=1.145577340.953156972.1370702221) functionality as part of Neo v2's CYPHER, though I am not sure if it is mainly a convenience factor and if its performance is similar to just executing Cypher queries in batches of, say, 40 000 via a Cypher transaction.

I would greatly appreciate any comments on functionality, workflow, and speed differences between these options.

Comment: For what its worth, I'm currently using Nigel Small's [load2neo](http://nigelsmall.com/load2neo) and it appears to work well and fast. In my mind, the geoff formatted text file is easier to construct than the CSV file with all properties as column headers, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking about using load2neo instead of the CSV batch importers. Are they similar in performance?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the latest version of Neo4j the recommended way is to use the new LOAD CSV statement in Cypher: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypherdoc-importing-csv-files-with-cypher.html

Comment: Do you know if the LOAD CSV statement is greatly different in terms of performance, from the [batch CSV importer](https://github.com/jexp/batch-import) utility?

Comment: My guess is that the batch importer is quite a bit faster because it's write only and much less flexible than having the whole cypher language at your disposal. I've personally loaded roughly 100 million nodes and relationships in about 40 minutes with the batch importer. Have not tried that same scale with LOAD CSV. I think it really depends on the amount of data, the flexibility you require for manipulation (you could always pre-process), and whether it will needed be repeated during the application lifetime as supposed to be a one time bulk import.